# bench-tps not working on v1.18.5

Tags: solana-cli, send-transaction, local-cluster, client

I have been locally testing some changes using cluster bootstrap command `./multinode-demo/bootstrap-validator.sh --gossip-host <public_ip>`. On the client side on another machine I usually use the cli command `solana-bench-tps --entrypoint <public_ip>:8001 --faucet <public_ip>:9900 --tx-count 1800 --duration 90`. My CLI version is **v1.18.5** and the repo branch where I build the validator is also **v1.18.5**. This setup works perfectly fine on **v1.17.13**.

Whats happens is that after running the bench-tps, it is stuck in the funding part where the bench tries to fund all the keypairs first before proceeding to the actual test. When I see the internal logs on the validator side, I see the transaction rate is very low (like under 100 transactions/s) so the funding never ends.

However, If I use the binary that is build by `cargo build --release` in the target folder of the same machine, instead of the CLI and use the `./multinode-demo/bench-tps.sh` script then it works just fine and the test ends successfully.

I want to know:
If I am missing some args?
Is my setup right?
Is there any known issue with the latest releases?